# Implementing a "Both, Either-or, but Not Null" Requirement in a Database

Tags: oracle, database-design

I have requirement for a web app that states that a user should be able to either upload an instruction document(s) (.pdf, .doc, .txt) or provide text for the instructions. The user can upload a document and provide text, or they can do one-or-the-other, but they have to do something (not nullable). How would this be designed in a database? Would this be considered a complete sub-type (see below)?

[image]
This is tiny part of a larger schema, so I just posted what I felt was necessary for this particular question.

Comment: Are you designing for a specific target DBMS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Ypercube's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10456998/533120) is fine, except this can, in fact, be done purely through declarative integrity while keeping separate tables. The trick is to combine deferred circular FOREIGN KEYs with a little bit of creative denormalization:

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE Instruction (
    InstructionId INT PRIMARY KEY,
    TextId INT UNIQUE,
    DocumentId INT UNIQUE,
    CHECK (
        (TextId IS NOT NULL AND InstructionId = TextId)
        OR (DocumentId IS NOT NULL AND InstructionId = DocumentId)
    )
);

CREATE TABLE Text (
    InstructionId INT PRIMARY KEY,
    FOREIGN KEY (InstructionId) REFERENCES Instruction (TextId) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE Document (
    InstructionId INT PRIMARY KEY,
    FOREIGN KEY (InstructionId) REFERENCES Instruction (DocumentId) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

ALTER TABLE Instruction ADD FOREIGN KEY (TextId) REFERENCES Text DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
ALTER TABLE Instruction ADD FOREIGN KEY (DocumentId) REFERENCES Document DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

Inserting Text is done like this:

```
INSERT INTO Instruction (InstructionId, TextId) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO Text (InstructionId) VALUES (1);
COMMIT;
```

Inserting Document like this:

```
INSERT INTO Instruction (InstructionId, DocumentId) VALUES (2, 2);
INSERT INTO Document (InstructionId) VALUES (2);
COMMIT;
```

And inserting both Text and Document like this:

```
INSERT INTO Instruction (InstructionId, TextId, DocumentId) VALUES (3, 3, 3);
INSERT INTO Text (InstructionId) VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO Document (InstructionId) VALUES (3);
COMMIT;
```

However, trying to insert Instruction alone **fails** on commit:

```
INSERT INTO Instruction (InstructionId, TextId) VALUES (4, 4);
COMMIT; -- Error (FOREIGN KEY violation).
```

Attempting to insert the "mismatched type" also **fails** on commit:

```
INSERT INTO Document (InstructionId) VALUES (1);
COMMIT; -- Error (FOREIGN KEY violation).
```

And of course, trying to insert bad values into Instruction **fails** (this time before commit):

```
INSERT INTO Instruction (InstructionId, TextId) VALUES (5, 6); -- Error (CHECK violation).
INSERT INTO Instruction (InstructionId) VALUES (7); -- Error (CHECK violation).
```

Comment: +1 I don't particularly like deferrable FKs but it's good to know it can be done (and how). Certainly useful if you want additional fields in the 2 child tables. @Branko: Does this work in Oracle and Postgres, too?

Comment: @ypercube The above was tested on Oracle 10.2. I'm not sure about PostgreSQL, but I see no reason why this technique shouldn't be portable to any DBMS with decent support for deferred FKs.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this cannot be done with Declarative Referential Integrity alone - not if your design has these 3 separate tables.

You'll have to ensure that all Insert/Delete/Update operations are done within transactions (stored procedures) that enforce such a requirement - so no row is ever inserted or left in table `Instruction` without a relative row in either one of the 2 other tables.

---

If you don't mind having nullable fields, you could merge the 3 tables into one and use a `CHECK` constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE Instruction
( InstructionID INT          NOT NULL
, Text          VARCHAR(255) NULL
, Filepath      VARCHAR(255) NULL
, PRIMARY KEY (InstructionID)
, CONSTRAINT Instruction_has_either_text_or_document 
    CHECK (Text IS NOT NULL OR FilePath IS NOT NULL)
) ;
```

Comment: I think this will satisfy the requirement. A senior on the team made the same sort of suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If a user submitted text, could your application save it as a .txt file?  This way you would only have to worry about dealing with files.

Answer (score 0):

Something feels a bit  off here

1. There is no `UserID` in this schema, so it should be added to the
   `Instruction` table.
2. If a user does not upload anything, there will (should) be no entry
   for that user in the `Instruction` table.
3. So the problem -- as stated -- is not about placing constraints
   on these three tables.
4. When loading this structure, use a stored procedure and/or  a transaction -- to make sure that at least one of the child record gets populated. Though, this has nothing to do with the business requirement that user has to upload something.

Comment: It's a big app. so I just posted this partial part of it. There's a users table and about 50 others I have to work on.