# Oracle Parent Table with 2 Possible Children Tables

Tags: oracle

If I have a parent table in Oracle, with two children, I know that I can enforce a FK so that the parent exists.

Is there a way to ensure that a child record only exists in one of the children, but not both?

In other words, disallow the insert into **child1** if there is already a record with the same **id** in **child1**?

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
  id         VARCHAR2(10)  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  some_date  VARCHAR2(10)
);


CREATE TABLE child1 (
  id         VARCHAR2(10)  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  some_date  VARCHAR2(10),
  FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES parent(id)
);


CREATE TABLE child2 (
  id         VARCHAR2(10)  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  some_date  VARCHAR2(10),
  FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES parent(id)
);
```

Comment: You'd have to write a trigger on both children to do the check on insert.

Comment: "disallow the insert into child1 if there is already a record with the same id in child1" You already implemented this check by having primary key. ;)

Comment: Create only one child table, and differentiate childs with a column.

Comment: See the answer by @Erwin in this question: [Complex foreign key constraint in SQLAlchemy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394177/complex-foreign-key-constraint-in-sqlalchemy/8395021#8395021) that uses `DEFERRABLE` foreign key constraints (under the **All key columns NOT NULL** title).

Comment: Another almost identical question and answer: [Implementing a “Both, Either-or, but Not Null” Requirement in a Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456525/implementing-a-both-either-or-but-not-null-requirement-in-a-database/10468475#10468475) (for Oracle this time)